# Pointer arithmetic on pointer of pointer (*argv[])?

Tags: c, pointers, math

I am aware that `foo[bar]` is equal to `*(foo + bar)`, but what is `*foo[bar]` equal to, such as accessing `*argv[2]`? I am somewhat confused in understanding this, I assumed maybe something like `*(*(foo) + bar)` but am unsure..

I apologize if this is a simple answer.

Comment: You could simply try it out. When in doubt, use parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my understanding that it is `**(foo + bar)`

Why?

`*foo[bar]` breaks down to * and `foo[bar]` since * is done after `foo[bar]` is dereferenced.

You already answered what `foo[bar] == *(foo + bar)`

Now add another * and you've got `*(*(foo + bar))`

Which also simplifies to `**(foo + bar)`

Answer (score 5):

`*a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a[b])` due to C and C++ precedence rules. so 
`*a[b]` is equivalent to `**(a+b)`

Comment: Ah! that is much simpler to understand. I knew it was simple, just need to wait 11 minutes to accept :P

Answer (score 3):

If the following are equivalent,

```
foo[bar]
*(foo + bar)
```

Then the following are equivalent too:

```
*foo[bar]
**(foo + bar)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your if part is meant to deal with the fact that * and [] can be overloaded?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I think the "If...then" is just demonstrating the process of logical deduction that can be followed to find the result.

Comment: @Armen:  Right; what @caf said.  Thanks for reading my mind, @caf.

Answer (score 0):

`*foo[bar]` is the pointer dereference to `foo[bar]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a declaration of `char *argv[]`, `argv[2]` refers to the third element of the `argv` array, which is a `char *`, and `*argv[2]` dereferences this pointer, giving you the first character in that string.