# Array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

If iptr is an array pointers then is there any difference between `**(iptr+3)` and `*iptr[3]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer arithmetic on pointer of pointer (*argv\[\])?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279584/pointer-arithmetic-on-pointer-of-pointer-argv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and, surprisingly (or not), also equivalent to `*(3[iptr])`.

Comment: @user987362 what is there to explain? It's the language. `x[3]` is equivalent to `3[x]`...

Comment: @user987362 It should be clear why `**(iptr+3)` is equivalent to `**(3+iptr)`. And that last one is equivalent to `*(3[iptr])`.

Comment: @Lucian I have another doubt is *iptr[3]=*(ip+3)

Comment: No, that one is not the same. `*(ip+3)` is equal to `ip[3]`.

Comment: @Lucian please check there is only one *

Comment: int f =5; int *p; p=&f.If so what happens..Is location of p changed to location of f

Comment: @user987362 the location of `p` itself is not changed. The location it points to is, to the memory location where f resides.

Comment: @user987362 or rather, you change what `p` points to. But `p` remains in the same memory.

Comment: Yes that is confusing me..In the above case if I print *p the value is 5.Is iptr[3]= (iptr+3)

Comment: @user987362 yes (first question) and no (iptr[3] is *(iptr+3)).

Comment: So *(iptr+3) gives the adress.Right?

Comment: @user987362 depends on how iptr is defined. If it's a double pointer, yes. If it's a simple pointer, no.

Answer (score 0):

there are nothing same between the `**(iptr+3)` and `*iptr[3]` since

`*iptr[3]` is the pointer representing the element having the address no-3 in the array

`**(iptr+3)`  and it's like if iptr is 3 than its **(6)

Comment: No, that's not correct.  If iptr were 3, then iptr+3 would only be 6 if iptr is a pointer to an 8-bit type (like char).  Pointer arithmetic doesn't work like regular arithmetic.  A mulitpiler is applied to scalars.

Comment: ya it is just a example not for the int its for only understand

Answer (score 0):

To the compiler, no, there is no difference. Both forms end up accessing the same element.

However, if you're writing code for the compiler, you've got the wrong audience. Your code should be written as if the next person to maintain it is a psychopath who knows where you live.

In other words, code for readability and maintainability, and let the compiler itself worry about optimisations <sup>(a)</sup>. To that end, I always prefer the `array[index]` form over the `*(array+index)` one since the former clarifies intent: the accessing of an array element.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Of course, as with most rules, there are exceptions. But, as with most exceptions, they're few and far between, so that advice stands.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same due to pointer arithmetic.

Suppose that you have a custom type

```
typedef struct
{
     /* add some parameters here */
} MyStruct;
```

And then create a vector of this type

```
MyStruct xMyStructArray[20];
```

When you want to access to, for example, the third element, you can do in one of following ways:

```
MyStruct xValue = xMyStructArray[2]; // index starts from zero
MyStruct xValue = xMyStructArray + 2;
```

xMyStructArray alone is seen as a pointer to the first array element.

xMyStructArray == &(xMyStructArray[0])

C/C++ creates an array in contiguous memory cells, and when you use the [] operator, you tell it to access to the respective cell of that array, starting from the pointer address corresponding to first array element address. So it knows the size of your type, and go to the right address.

The pointer arithmetic works the same. When you sum 1 to a pointer, the compiler checks the size of the type corresponding to that pointer, and then goes to the next position in memory compatible with that type.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, Compiler will treat `iptr[3]` and `3[iptr]` as `*(iptr+3)` and `*(3+iptr)` only.

`int a[5][10] = {0};` Consider this 2 dimentional array. Here `a[i][j]` means `*(*(a+i) + j)`, so we can write like `i[a][j]` also which means `*(*(i + a) + j)`.

But `i[j][a]` is wrong, because it will be treated as `*(*(i + j)+a)` which is wrong. `*(i+j)` will leads to crash(undefined behaviour).